# How to change div content when background-slider go next/prev

Tags: jquery, slideshow

how do I change the contents of a div according to the background image of the background page?

Like this one:

http://www.sap.com/index.epx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so then add some square icons, text - whatever trigger you want that would change the background and add the onclick event to it like this:

```
<div id="myDivTag">
    <img src="/Image/SquareIcon.gif" onclick="changeBackground()" />
</div>
```

And then modify the line of code from my other post that changes it, to change the div tag:

```
document.getElementById("myDivTag").style.backgroundImage = backImage[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot. But there's a way to change texts inside a div tag while background change?

Comment: You mean like this?

    document.getElementById("myDivTag").style.innerHTML = "this is my text"; 

?

Answer (score 0):

modify your dropdown to be something like this:

```
<select id="myDropDown" onchange="changeBackground()">
<option value="0">Image 1</option>
<option value="1">Image 2</option>
</select>
```

add a new javascript function to your head section:

```
var backImage[0] = "/Images/33.jpg";
var backImage[1] = "/Images/34.jpg";    
function changeBackground() {
    if (document.getElementById("myDropDown").value = "0" {
        document.body.background = backImage[1];
    } else {
        document.body.background = backImage[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm not using a dropdown menu, I'm using a div and the images it will be changed like the site I posted in my question. (http://www.sap.com/index.epx)